# Docker - Windows Server 2016 Nano Server or IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, docker, iis

***Official images for .NET Core for Linux and Windows Server 2016 Nano Server***

I have a question about this docker image;
We have ASP.NET and VB.NET for our legacy apps and they're all running on IIS server.
I am wondering if the official microsoft image for .net core will only support the Windows Server 2016 Nano Server and NOT the IIS server? Sorry new to .net world.
I need to dockerize our ASP.NET and VB.NET apps running on IIS but not sure if that image is only for Windows Server 2016 Nano Server; will IIS server work with that official microsof image?

Answer (score 0):

For traditional ASP.NET apps, running them on Docker requires the base image to be Windows Server Core,

[image: Docker image composition]

More information can be found in my blog post,

https://blog.lextudio.com/traditional-asp-net-on-docker-images-1af3b72eeaaf